# Is there a reason why Python standard library packages/modules are not in a package named python?

Tags: python, package, standard-library

as it is done in Java... This makes the task of asserting if a package/module belongs to the standard library trivial. I'd guess this is just a convention. Are there any plans to change this in the future?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python packages from outside the standard library are occasionally adopted into the standard library.  If there were a naming convention to distinguish them, you'd have to rename the modules, and this would break existing code for no good reason.

For example, argparse was not always part of the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

According to [PEP 20](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), "Flat is better than nested".

The Python style guide discourages using nested packages, and the standard library (mostly) follows this convention.